# Structure for referencing HTML elements from Javascript in MVC3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, identifier

We have an ASP.NET MVC3 project. We populate several parts of our site using ajax calls. Lets say we have a `div` in our `cshtml` where we want to put some search results.

```
<div id="SearchResult" />
```

We have created a list with constants for all elements that we want to refer in our Javascript files

```
var selectors = {
    SearchResult: '#SearchResult',
    ...
};
```

When we want access the `div` we use `selectors.SearchResult` in our Javascripts.

So far, so good. But coming from a c# world where we have strong bindings, compile time warnings, etc, we think the coupling here is a little bit on the loose side. If we want to refactor our `div` ids we have to be very careful to find all references and update them.

Are there any good practices for keeping javascript and HTML identifiers in sync? Any templates/scripts for extracting all `div` ids into a javascript file?

Comment: `If we want to refactor our div ids we have to be very careful to find all references and update them`   - 
for a given id, how many references do you have in your cshtml?

Comment: In each cshtml usually one, but each id in a cshtml is usually referenced in 0-5 locations in 1-3 different JS files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a script to the view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.viewConfig = { searchResult: '#SearchResult' };
</script>
```

and have your JS files read this `window.viewConfig.searchResult`.

---

You could also take this further and store the id in a variable and use it.

```
@{
    var myId = "SearchResult";
}
```

then use `@myId` so the div would be

```
<div id="@myId"></div>
```

and the script would be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.viewConfig = { searchResult: '#@myid' };
</script>
```